# Simultaneous multiple inheritance both in composed class and its components (Python)

Tags: python, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Earlier I had a simple single-inheritance architecture between two classes `C1` and `C2`, which worked well:

```
class C1:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print("C1")

class C2(C1):
    def __init__(self, z, *args):
        C1.__init__(self, *args)
        self.z = z
        print("C2")

c2 = C2(1, 2, 3) # prints "C1" and "C2"
print(c2.x, c2.y, c2.z) # prints 2 3 1
```

Now the architecture has become more complicated:

```
class _B1: # abstract base
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print("B1")
class _B2(_B1): # concrete base
    def __init__(self, z, *args):
        _B1.__init__(self, *args)
        self.z = z
        print("B2")

class _M1: # abstract mixin
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        print("M1")
class _M2(_M1): # concrete mixin
    def __init__(self, *args):
        _M1.__init__(self, *args)
        print("M2")

class C1(_M1, _B1): # abstract composed
    def __init__(self, x, y): # old signature must not be changed
        _B1.__init__(self, x)
        _M1.__init__(self, y)
        print("C1")
class C2(_M2, _B2, C1): # concrete composed; use C1 here because isinstance(c2, C1) must still return True
    def __init__(self, z, *args): # old signature must not be changed
        C1.__init__(self, *args) # works
        _B2.__init__(self, z, x) # Problem 1a: cannot do that because x is abstracted in *args
        _M2.__init__(self, y) # Problem 1b: cannot do that because y is abstracted in *args
        # Problem 2: there seem to be "two versions" of B1 and M1 (one from C1 and one from B2 or M2, resp.), and so the constructors are each called twice
        print("C2")

# c2 = C2(1, 2, 3)
# print(c2.x, c2.y, c2.z)
```

As stated in the code, I cannot figure out how to pass the arguments to the constructors. Also the fact that the constructors are called twice gives me the feeling that this is a bad design; however, from an OOP perspective, I could not think of a more accurate one.

I am aware of some workarounds, but I would prefer a canonical solution. In particular, I would not want to include `x` and `y` in `C2.__init__`.

Comment: You have [diamond inheritence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) I would strongly reconsider your design. In general you should [prefer composition over inheritence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) as a class that inherits from 3 direct base classes (plus more indirect bases) smells of poor design.

Comment: To get around Problem 1, if you know the order in which `x` and `y` will be supplied, you could just index into `args` to find them. For example, if it is known that `x` is the first argument after `z` and `y` the second, then `x = args[0]` and `y = args[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is why `super` exists.

```
class _B1: # abstract base
    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x
        print("B1")


class _B2(_B1): # concrete base
    def __init__(self, z, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.z = z
        print("B2")


class _M1: # abstract mixin
    def __init__(self, y, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.y = y
        print("M1")


class _M2(_M1): # concrete mixin
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("M2")


class C1(_M1, _B1):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("C1")


class C2(_M2, _B2, C1):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("C2")


c2 = C2(x=1, y=2, z=3)
print(c2.x, c2.y, c2.z)
```

The output:

```
B1
M1
C1
B2
M2
C2
1 2 3
```

Some things to note:

1. Every `__init__` accepts arbitrary keyword arguments, and passes any it doesn't handle itself to `super().__init__`.
2. Each `__init__` calls `super.__init__` *once*; properly defined, each class in the hierarchy will be reached.
3. Done correctly, `**kwargs` will be empty by the time `object.__init__` is called. For example, when `C2.__init__` is called, its `kwargs` contains `x=1`, `y=2`, and `z=3`, all of which are passed on to `M2.__init__`, which passes them to `B2.__init__`. Because `B2.__init__` declares `z` by name, its `kwargs` contains only `x=1` and `y=2`, so those are passed on, but `z` is not. `B1` is the class in this case that calls `object.__init__`, but by this time each of `x`, `y`, and `z` has been "consumed" by one method or another.
4. When you actually instantiate `C2`, you use keywords arguments to avoid concerns over which positional arguments are handled by which method.
5. If you removed the calls to `print`; you wouldn't need to define `C2.__init__`, `C1.__init__`, or `M2.__init__` at all.

Comment: Nice solution; ironically I thought, my case were too complex to use super(). However, the part with the keyword arguments in C2.__init__ and C1.__init__ is cheating: All classes who relied on the old signature (and thus did not use keyword arguments) would have to be changed now.

Comment: Well, yes: you often *do* have to change what you've done wrong, regardless of *why* it was wrong.